# Regex pattern in Typescript

Tags: regex, typescript, pattern-matching, angular2-forms

This pattern works, but it the opposite way than I intended, how do I change it so when I the pattern is matched, it causes an error? Thanks.

```
   <mat-form-field style="text-align: center">
                <input type="text" pattern="^([aA]\d{6})" placeholder="id" matInput="text" formControlName="id"
                  name="id" required> 
              </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Use `pattern="^(?![aA]\d{6}$).*"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, this works.

Answer (score 0):

Your current pattern matches a string that starts with `a` or `A` and then has strictly 6 digits. The `^` is redundant in `pattern` regex since it is anchored by default.

So, in fact, the current regex is `^[Aa]\d{6}$`, and to write a reverse HTML5 pattern you may use

```
pattern="(?![aA]\d{6}$).*"
```

This pattern will get parsed as `/^(?:(?![aA]\d{6}$).*)$/` pattern (with `u` modifier in Chrome, Firefox and other browsers supporting this feature).

The `(?![Aa]\d{6}$)` negative lookahead will fail any string that starts with `a` or `A` and then having 6 digits to its end.

The `.*` matches any 0+ chars. Use `.+` to match any 1 or more chars. This part is required since the HTML5 regex should match the whole input.

HTML5 demo:

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
  border: 5px solid #dadadada;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
input:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none;
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="(?![aA]\d{6}$).*" title="Please enter a valid string." placeholder="Please enter valid text" />
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```